# selectOneMenu with converter. java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, converters

Sorry for my bad english.

I try to show a selectOneMenu using converter but throws error:

java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to pojos.HoraRango

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to pojos.HoraRango
at managedBeans.HoraRangoConverter.getAsString(HoraRangoConverter.java:46)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:114)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:61)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeLabel(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:202)
at or
```

my xhtml

```
 <p:outputLabel for="console" value="Basic:" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{bPistasDisponibles.inicioHoraElegido}" style="width:125px" converter="HoraRangoConverter">
           <f:selectItems value="#{bPistasDisponibles.inicioHora}" var="inicioHora" 
                       itemLabel="#{inicioHora.hora}" itemValue="#{inicioHora}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

my converter

```
   public class HoraRangoConverter implements Converter{
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
        try {
             DaoHoraRango daohoraRango =  new DaoImplHoraRango();
             HoraRango cat= daohoraRango.verHoraRango(Integer.parseInt(value));
            return cat;

        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid Cine."));
        }
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if(value != null) {
        return String.valueOf(((HoraRango)value).getIdHoraRango());
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: I guess that your problem is, that you parse an `java.lang.Integer` object as parameter for the variable value in you method `public String getAsString(...)`... And you cant't cast an `java.lang.Integer` to an `HoraRango` object...

Comment: Thanks buts finally i resolved the problem. The problem is in the bean.

Comment: @taritatanta then please, either remove your question or post your answer.

Comment: The problem is simple, arraylist is wrong. I think that my problem not help anyone. I dont know how remove the question